# shotgun for django?

Tags: python, django, sinatra, shotgun

I like [shotgun server](http://rtomayko.github.com/shotgun/). but is there any similar package available for Django development ?

shotgun reloads the server every time the code is changed , thus making the development process easier .. I am looking for a similar kind of program for Django development .

Thanks !

Comment: The Django development server also reloads whenever code is changed (but not when new files are added).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Django Dev server that is supplied.  OR you could use something similar to this:

http://jeffbaier.com/articles/installing-django-on-an-ubuntu-linux-server/

This will reload the server at each request, **but make sure to turn it off before production!**

Edit:

The part you really need is just this: MaxRequestsPerChild 1 located near the bottom.  You could read the article just to understand what they are working with though.